# Need help with modelling a cylinder with a piece cut out?

Tags: modeling

I need to model a cylinder with a piece cut out (a quarter of it), but I can seem to get it with nice edges:

Test 1: Even with the a bevel added, the middle part is distorted.

[image]
[image: Test 1]

Test 2 Added more mesh to the top to 'fix' it, but the mesh at the bottom is ruined.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this topology doesn't work too bad. You'll have to move a bit some edges to prevent a bit of pinching, I don't know if it can be perfect with an only 12 vertices cylinder though.

[image]

Comment: this topology looks great. How did you get the topology for the bottom corner? Do you bevel and the use 'knife' to cut?

Comment: you need to create bevels all around, then create an additional horizontal edge loop not to far below, then use the knife or just join the vertices with J.

Answer (score 1):

You can bevel it in two passes:

[image]

Make sure to alt select the inner edges so that the selection reaches the center and most outer parts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I entirely understand the problem, however here is what I would do before bevelling the edges:

- remove duplicate vertices (in edit mode choose vertex select mode, select all, right click[*] and choose merge vertices by distance)
- recalculate normals (in edit mode press SHIFT+N)
- apply scale (in object mode press CTRL+A and choose scale)
- add "Edge split" modifier
- bevel the edges in edit mode and try out the different types of outer and inner miter. You can find those if you expand the little window that appears on the bottom left after applying the bevelling

EDIT:
Also add more bevel segments.

[*] If you are still using blender 2.79 or 2.8 with right-click-select then you can access this menu by pressing W. Also, "merge vertices" is the name in 2.8 but in 2.79 it was called "remove doubles"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I did try all of the above before coming here. including 'auto-smooth', 'mark sharp'.

my hunch is that there is something wrong with the mesh flow, when it bevels, it creates triangle at the corners. But I can't think of any other way to model this shape.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this method. Here is the topology

[image]

[image]

[image]